# Spark Executor hang on ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator remote fetches

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am running some Sedona geospatial queries on top of a Spark cluster hosted in the Amazon EMR environment. My query works for some input datasets, but would hang on the 'count()' method of Spark SQL against the result dataset, when the input datasets are slightly larger. Taking about 200K records in the results.

**Environment: **
Amazon emr-6.2.0, Hadoop distribution:Amazon, spark 3.0.1
Java Version    1.8.0_362 (Amazon.com Inc.)
Scala Version   version 2.12.10

**Cluster config: **
master: 1 c5.2xlarge;    core:   2xc5.2xlarge    task:   2xc5.2xlarge
[Executors' states](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QiIo.png)

**Symptoms**

Some executors will go through, some others will get stuck as shown. For the executors that hang, it usually takes less than a minute to enter that state, and time spent on Java Garbage Collection (GC) does not seem to be a concern.

When the count() eventually timed out, the driver log will stop at a point like this:

23/03/30 19:25:50 INFO **TypeUtil: JVM Runtime does not support Modules**
23/03/30 19:25:50 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_9_piece0 on ip-10-11-1-20.ec2.internal:42955 in memory (size: 9.6 KiB, free: 5.9 GiB)
23/03/30 19:25:50 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_8_piece0 on ip-10-11-1-20.ec2.internal:42955 in memory (size: 9.0 KiB, free: 5.9 GiB)
23/03/30 19:25:50 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_8_piece0 on ip-10-11-1-54.ec2.internal:45875 in memory (size: 9.0 KiB, free: 4.9 GiB)
23/03/30 19:25:50 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_8_piece0 on ip-10-11-1-190.ec2.internal:37043 in memory (size: 9.0 KiB, free: 4.9 GiB)

On the executors that hang, it appears they all get stuck at a point where they try to fetch a remote data block:

23/03/30 19:23:59 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 3 (146.8 MiB) non-empty blocks including 2 (119.9 MiB) local and 0 (0.0 B) host-local and 1 (26.9 MiB) remote blocks
23/03/30 19:23:59 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to ip-10-11-1-190.ec2.internal/10.11.1.190:7337 after 1 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
23/03/30 19:23:59 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 1 remote fetches in 21 ms
23/03/30 19:23:59 INFO MapOutputTrackerWorker: Don't have map outputs for shuffle 2, fetching them
23/03/30 19:23:59 INFO MapOutputTrackerWorker: Doing the fetch; tracker endpoint = NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark://MapOutputTracker@ip-10-11-1-20.ec2.internal:39923)
23/03/30 19:23:59 INFO MapOutputTrackerWorker: Got the output locations
23/03/30 19:23:59 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 2 (5.7 MiB) non-empty blocks including 0 (0.0 B) local and 0 (0.0 B) host-local and 2 (5.7 MiB) remote blocks
23/03/30 19:23:59 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to ip-10-11-1-204.ec2.internal/10.11.1.204:7337 after 1 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
23/03/30 19:23:59 INFO **ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 1 remote fetches in 2 ms**

And the overall query failed likely because the remote fetch never returns.

This is very puzzling since it works for some of my input datasets but not others. Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

I have tried to run the same job on larger spark clusters with 5 amazon c5d.x4large task VMs, but that did not help.

Comment: Can you give an obfuscated example that will produce the failure?